# Including headers with libiota

Tags: c++, google-weave

I built libiota as instructed in [the weave guide](https://developers.google.com/weave/guides/device-dev/getting-started), and installed it using:

```
make -j lib
sudo make install
```

This installed /usr/bin/libiota.a and header files in /usr/include/iota/.

Now I am trying to compile the following simple program (main.cc):

```
#include <iota/daemon.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

with: `g++ main.cc`

and I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/iota/daemon.h:28:0,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/iota/schema/traits/goog_device.h:27:58: fatal error: include/iota/schema/traits/goog_device_enums.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "include/iota/schema/traits/goog_device_enums.h"
                                                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Apparently goog_device.h includes a file relative to /usr/ and not /usr/include...

Is there something wrong with my usage of the library ? What is the recommended way to include header files ?

I am using commit b53901b6cc516941f1432da030eb3c76c213fbea, from February 2nd 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in the way we have included headers. We will fix this in a future release. Could you please add an include path to -I/usr/ in your application make-file as a workaround for now?

thanks
Bhaskar

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I see that there were improvements in commit 94f837444ae8f9ed26acca33ff21d7d93f9b2178 already ! I ended up putting the include dir, the libiota root dir (for headers in the platform/ subdir), and the third_party/jsmn dir in the search path to have everything compile.